# Joining two char arrays and a char with no dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, char, arduino

I'm trying to print 2 char arrays and a char together to the serial port of an arduino. Because the SRAM I'm working with is limited, I'm trying to keep away from any dynamically allocated stuff (like combining them into a string just for the purpose of putting them into the Serial println function).

```
void myStuff(char* x,char* param)
Serial.println((x+'='+param));
```

How can I join x,'=', and param without allocating a new variable? Am I following the best practice here for memory management?

-added: the serial is attached to another device and it does respond if the command is not sent on one line with a println. ie mulitple Serial.prints with a CRLF at the end dont work.

-edited out the function that was not working to begin with

Comment: `Serial.print(x); Serial.print("="); Serial.println(param);`

Comment: I should add: the serial is attached to another device and it does not appear to respond if the command is not sent on one line with a println.

Comment: "This works." Well perhaps it compiles. But have you verified it's actually doing what you intended?

Comment: You're right. I assumed it was working because it was printing the correct response. Its just printing stuff from memory.

Comment: Serial.print(x + '?') actually does Serial.print( (char*)((size_t)x + 63)

C++ doesn't overload + to mean string concatenation. @RedAlert had the correct answer.